# Base 64 decoding byte[] casted into a string

Tags: java, android

I got some encoded log information, casted into a string for transmitting purpose (the cast might be ugly but it works).

I'm trying to cast it back to a byte[] in order to decode it but it's not working:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = android.util.Base64.encode((login + ":" + password).getBytes(), NO_WRAP);
String encoded = "Authentification " + encodedBytes;

String to_decode = encoded.substring(17);
byte[] cast1 = to_decode;            // error
byte[] cast2 = (byte[]) to_decode;   // error
byte[] cast3 = to_decode.getBytes();
// no error, but i get something totally different from encodedBytes (the array is even half the size of encodedBytes)
// and when i decode it i got an IllegalArgumentException
```

these 3 casts are not working, any idea?

Comment: You cant just cast String to byte[]... Nor can you just set it. The last one will turn the string into bytes, but not from a base 64 representation.

Comment: yea i know that's my problem. im trying to get my string back to a base 64 representations so i can then decode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

In general, you need to use `Base64.decode` in order to reverse the result of `Base64.encode`:

```
byte[] data = android.util.Base64.decode(to_decode, DEFAULT);
```

In general, you should always ask yourself "How did I perform the conversion from type X to type Y?" when working out how to get back from type Y to type X.

Note that you've got a typo in your code too - "Authentification" should be "Authentication".

However, you've *also* got a problem with your encoding - you're creating a `byte[]`, and using string concatenation with that will call `toString()` on the byte array, which is *not* what you want. You should call `encodeToString` instead. Here's a complete example:

```
String prefix = "Authentication "; // Note fix here...
// TODO: Don't use basic authentication; it's horribly insecure.
// Note the explicit use of ASCII here and later, to avoid any ambiguity.
byte[] rawData = (login + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
String header = prefix + Base64.encodeToString(rawData, NO_WRAP);

// Now to validate...
String toDecode = header.substring(prefix.length());
byte[] decodedData = Base64.decode(toDecode, DEFAULT);
System.out.println(new String(decodedData, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

Comment: it doesn't work neither, doing this seems to be same as: byte[] data = android...decode(to_decode.getBytes(), DEFAULT);

Comment: @TheoJouret: It really *does* work. How are you determining that it doesn't? (I would strongly advise *against* calling `to_decode.getBytes()` at all, but I'd expect that version to work as well, given that you're calling Base64.decode.)

Comment: to_decode.getBytes() gives me something totally different from the encodedBytes I had at first, and when i try to decode it i get an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: lol thx for the note on Authentication, though this is not in my code. I can't change the way data is encoded and casted to string, this is not my code and I have to deal with it.

Comment: @TheoJouret: So what we don't know is how many of the 3 errors are in your *real* code...

Comment: @TheoJouret: "I can't change the way data is encoded and casted to string" - then you have no hope. The result of your code simply doesn't include the data you need. Sorry about that, but it's just impossible. You *cannot* get back from a string like `"[B@1c898b41"` which is the kind of thing you'll have, and is the result of calling `toString()` on a `byte[]`, back to the content of that byte array. The data just isn't there.

Comment: thx for answer. im giving it a try but this is on client side and i dont have access to server

Comment: @TheoJouret: It's not clear what you mean by "this" - but if the code that's using "String value = "Authentication " + someByteArray;` is somewhere you can't get at it, you need to raise that as an issue. That code is fundamentally broken.

Comment: actually it works with Base64.encodeToString instead of Base64.encode; and i can decode it after. I thought it would change the way data are encoded and that the server wouldn't understand the request but it works !

Comment: the other solution is, when casting a byte[] to a string, doing String str = new String(someByteArray) instead of something like String str = someByteArray.toString() or String str = "..." + someByteArray

Comment: anyway your comment is the solution, i would upvote you if i could but i still dont have enough reputation points

Comment: @TheoJouret: Firstly, that's not casting. And secondly, you should *only* do that when you know the byte array actually represents encoded text - in which case you should specify the encoding explicitly.